# sas, how can i retrieve a value from regression result and assign to a variable

Tags: sas

how i can do if I want to assign i to intercept to make i = 906.73916.thanks

  ```
                                      Parameter Estimates

                                              Parameter       Standard
  Variable     Label                  DF       Estimate          Error    t Value    Pr > |t|

  Intercept    Intercept               1      906.73916       28.26505      32.08      <.0001
  acs_k3       avg class size k-3      1       -2.68151        1.39399      -1.92      0.0553
  meals        pct free meals          1       -3.70242        0.15403     -24.04      <.0001
  full         pct full credential     1        0.10861        0.09072       1.20      0.2321
  ```

Answer (score 0):

ODS is very helpful for this.  The names of different output components differ for different procs.  Example for PROC REG below, should be about the same for most regression PROCS:

```
ods output ParameterEstimates=MyIntercept(where=(Variable="Intercept"));

proc reg data=sashelp.class;
  model weight=age;
run;
quit;

ods output close;

proc print data=MyIntercept;
run;
```